# how to compare two columns with R

Tags: r, compare

I have a data frame and i'am tryng to compare two columns with this command :

```
table_NDCG=table_NDCG%>%group_by(requete)%>%mutate(comparaison=ifelse(url_cliquee.x==url_cliquee.y,TRUE,FALSE))
```

and this erros appears :

> Error in Ops.factor(url_cliquee.x, url_cliquee.y) :    level sets of
>   factors are different

```
ifelse("http://intranet.com.intraorange#/{840f69af-91e4-44f5-a1b1-1940fb5edf54}/{962e8297-b167-4bf4-ad43-2360d64ca220}/{5f7cc0e2-6b03-4a92-b05b-813a0f5446eb}/3360/[http:||intranet.com.intraorange|fr|Pages|vifSR_06022019.aspx]   "=="    http://intranet-obs.com.ftgroup/obs/spip.php?article8070",TRUE,FALSE)
```

This is a real exemple with my data :
sorry i can't post more there are confidential informations

```
> ifelse("http://intranet.com.intraorange#/{840f69af-91e4-44f5-a1b1-1940fb5edf54}/{962e8297-b167-4bf4-ad43-2360d64ca220}/{5f7cc0e2-6b03-4a92-b05b-813a0f5446eb}/3360/[http:||intranet.com.intraorange|fr|Pages|vifSR_06022019.aspx] "=="    http://intranet-obs.com.ftgroup/obs/spip.php?article8070",TRUE,FALSE)
[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error returns, it seems that the factor levels are different. Check the levels using

```
levels(url_cliquee.x)
levels(url_cliquee.y)
```

and make sure they are the same to be comparable

Comment: For example if you have two vectors A and B let's say containing color factors like "Blue" and "Green" the "levels" comand should return "Blue", "Green". 
But if B contains "Red", the levels would be different between A and B and the comparison could not be made. 

Each URL seems to correspond to one factor level and this could be the problem. You can try to convert these factors to character string which are easier to compare. Use  "as.character" command like

url_cliquee.x <- as.character(url_cliquee.x)

Comment: i tried this ```table_NDCG=table_NDCG%>%group_by(requete)%>%mutate(comparaison=ifelse(levels(url_cliquee.x)==levels(url_cliquee.y),TRUE,FALSE))```|  another error appears ```Error: Column `comparaison` must be length 50 (the group size) or one, not 6116
In addition: Warning message:
In levels(url_cliquee.x) == levels(url_cliquee.y) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length```

Comment: Are your columns url_cliquee.x and url_cliquee.b the same length ?

Comment: when i add as.character it works :D Thanks a lot for help

Comment: You're welcome ! 
You can validate the answer to allow  future users to find answers to  related questions

Answer (score 0):

table_NDCG=table_NDCG%>%group_by(requete)%>%mutate(comparaison=ifelse(as.character(url_cliquee.x)==as.character(url_cliquee.y),TRUE,FALSE))